# how to redirect to particular URL while clicking on button in android?

Tags: android, redirect, android-button

I want to redirect user to particular URL while clicking on `Button` in Android App.

Comment: What is your actual question? Did you already try something and then failed? How is this Anroid related?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can start a 'view' activity, which would be the browser given a URL:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Assuming you are using xml layout
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent viewIntent =
          new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
            Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"));
          startActivity(viewIntent);
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Better to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW instead of "android.intent.action.VIEW"

Answer (score 0):

Update #2023:

If you are using in `View-Activity`:

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL_HERE)))
```

If you are using in `Compose-View`:

```
@Composable
fun YourComposable() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    context.apply {
        startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL_HERE)))
    }
}
```