# How to redirect to URL from Fragment using a button

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236413/how-to-redirect-to-particular-url-while-clicking-on-button-in-android) for redirecting from an activity,

but I couldn't find a way doing so from a `Fragment`.

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        ...

        view.myButton.setOnClickListener {
            val urlIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(WEBSITE_URL))

            startActivity(urlIntent)
        }

        return view
    }
```

The above code produces exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat="https://www.google.com/" }

I got **Main Activity** instance (as `MainActivity.instance`) so 
I tried to use `setClass` and `setComponent` to try and handle the `Intent`, without a success.

Comment: Hey did you try this way?

getActivity().startActivity(urlIntent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's worked, where `MainActivity.instance` is the fragment's host instance.
Get the host using `requireActivity()` an so on.

```
    view.myButton.setOnClickListener {
        val urlIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        urlIntent.data = Uri.parse(WEBSITE_URL)
        MainActivity.instance.startActivity(urlIntent)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Ty for the answer but it still gets an exception because I'm in `fragment`, I need some how to add the `MainActivity.instance` to handle the intent.

Comment: Inside fragment you could get host instance of activity with getter `activity`.

Comment: I got the host, but how do I use it?

Comment: Also fragment has method `requireActivity()` which return activity not nullable.

Comment: Could you describe more information about what you need. It seems in activity you have webView? And you what to open url inside him??

Comment: You gave me a clue and it worked, just to use `MainActivity.instance.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Okay, no problem.